# Swift: How to zoom an image as I scroll up in scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I'm trying to zoom my image view as I scroll the scrollView past the top of the screen. Here's my code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if (offset <= 0) {
        let ratio: CGFloat = -offset*1.0 / UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        self.coverImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0 + ratio, y: 1.0 + ratio)
    }
}
```

This zooms the image as I scroll up, but because I am also scrolling up, **my view goes down, and reveals the white background behind the image as it expands**. How do I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a scroll view is not really suited to what you are trying to do. How about using a gesture recognizer instead? Something along these lines:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  coverImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPan))
  coverImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
}

func didPan(panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
  let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: coverImageView)
  if translation.y > 0 {
    let zoomRatio = (translation.y * 0.1) + 1.0
    coverImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: zoomRatio, y: zoomRatio)
  }
}
```

You'll have to play around to get it to behave exactly how you want, but it should be enough to get you started.